# Fit Variogram Iteration Warning

Tags: r, interpolation, kriging, variogram, gstat

I would like to perform kriging using a variable call "Secchi.Disk" from a data set I have. However, when fitting the variogram I get the following warming message

```
Warning message:
In fit.variogram(v, vgm(0.5, "Sph", 40, 0.5)) :
  No convergence after 200 iterations: try different initial values?
```

I been trying different values for the partial sill, range and nugget; but, I still get the same warning message. Here is my code

```
library(rgdal)     
library(ggplot2)   
library(ggmap)
library(GISTools)
library(sp)
library(spdep)
library(gstat)

all.data<-read.csv("C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/All_Data_Fall_17.csv", header=TRUE)
str(all.data)
dput(all.data)
coordinates(all.data)<- ~ Lat + Lon
class(all.data)

#Variogram
#Secchi
v <- variogram(all.data$Secchi.Disk~1, all.data)
plot(v)
v.fit <- fit.variogram(v, vgm(0.5,"Sph",40,0.5))
```

Dataset `View(all.data)`
[image]

Output `dput(data.frame(all.data)[,c("Lat","Lon","Secchi.Disk")])`

```
structure(list(Lat = c(334374, 334381, 334391, 334423, 334426, 
334431, 334465, 334455, 334444, 334481, 334481, 334489), Lon = c(4088957, 
4089003, 4089040, 4089041, 4088984, 4088965, 4089025, 4088982, 
4088924, 4088929, 4089004, 4089039), Secchi.Disk = c(18L, 15L, 
16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 16L)), .Names = c("Lat", 
"Lon", "Secchi.Disk"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Output of str(all.data)

```
Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 12 obs. of  11 variables:
  .. ..$ Sample.ID  : Factor w/ 12 levels "CL-1","CL-10",..: 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 2 ...
  .. ..$ Temp       : num [1:12] 23 26.1 25.1 24.9 24.4 ...
  .. ..$ TDS        : num [1:12] 0.542 0.517 0.53 0.542 0.535 0.535 0.539 0.527 0.536 0.536 ...
  .. ..$ pH         : num [1:12] 8.08 8.74 8.67 8.51 8.69 8.7 8.56 8.75 8.63 8.6 ...
  .. ..$ ODOsat     : num [1:12] 60.9 216.1 156.7 112.6 114.8 ...
  .. ..$ TSS        : num [1:12] 68.3 68.8 67.5 65.4 56 ...
  .. ..$ TP         : num [1:12] 3.27 3.05 4.02 2.99 3.25 3.17 3.27 3.15 4.02 3.38 ...
  .. ..$ TN         : num [1:12] 13 12.4 12 12.4 15 12.6 12.4 12.4 12 13.6 ...
  .. ..$ NO3.N      : num [1:12] 2.71 3.02 2.71 1 2.58 1.35 1.66 1.88 4.07 4.16 ...
  .. ..$ Chloro.a   : num [1:12] 274 464 416 375 236 ...
  .. ..$ Secchi.Disk: int [1:12] 18 15 16 15 15 15 17 16 16 17 ...
  ..@ coords.nrs : int [1:2] 2 3
  ..@ coords     : num [1:12, 1:2] 334374 334381 334391 334423 334426 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:12] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Lat" "Lon"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 334374 4088924 334489 4089041
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Lat" "Lon"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
```

Output of `plot(v)` 
[image: Output of plot (v)]
Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show the plot?

Comment: Yes, I have added the plot as you requested.

Comment: Can you give us the data? Do you only have 12 measurements?

Comment: Yes @Spacedman. As requested I have uploaded the data. Thank you

Comment: Given that the only numbers pertinent to your error are lat, long, and Secchi.Disk, any chance you could supply them in a computer readable form rather than a screen dump? `dput(data.frame(all.data)[,c("Lat","Lon","Secchi.Disk")])`  (or similar) might do it, its only 36 numbers.

Comment: Yes @Spacedman. As requested I have uploaded the data following your suggested format.

Comment: @Spacedman, thank you for your solution. However, I would like to ask you another question. Keeping in mind that the final purpose of this variogram in to perform kriging,(and taking into account your concerns) do you believe this is a valid approach?  if not, which approach do you think is more valid?

Comment: You can do it, but the standard errors might swamp any variation. Also, I'm a bit worried that you have integer values because kriging in gstat assumes a Gaussian response. But this discussion is for another question or another place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I extend the range of the variogram a bit you'll get a few more data points in your variogram. I couldn't get a Spherical model to fit, but an Exponential one does:

```
> v <- variogram(Secchi.Disk~1, data=d, cutoff=150)
> vs.fit <- fit.variogram(v, vgm(1,"Exp",100,1))
> plot(v,vs.fit)
```

[image]

I think with 12 data points and only integer values, this is going to be very unstable.... To illustrate that, here's the variogram *cloud* for your 12 points which is composed of 11*12/2 = 66 points:

```
> v <- variogram(Secchi.Disk~1, data=d, cutoff=150,cloud=TRUE)
> plot(v,ylim=c(-.5,5))
```

[image]

You are trying to fit a smooth curve to something like that...